# Column by Column Comparison in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have two files

File1

```
Row   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  
1      A     B    C     D  
2      E     F    G     H
```

File2

```
Row   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  
1      A     Z    C     D  
2      E     F    Y     H  
3      M     N    O     P
```

Requirement is to have row by row and then column by column Comparison. With this two output files are required to be created. 
First will have Row 3 from file2 which states these rows are new in file2.
Second file will have this output:

```
FileName  Row  ColName  ColValue  
File1     1     Col2    B (--this is old value)  
File2     1     Col2    Z (--this is new value) 

File1     2     Col3    G  
File2     2     Col3    Y
```

Now to get rows which are missing in file1 but present in file2 can be done by

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next;}!($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

But not sure how to generate the second output file.

Comment: Is that meant to be `File2` in the last row of output? Are the row numbers physically present in the files?  What combination of columns tells you that the entry in File1 matches the entry in File2?  It could be just the row number, or the row number plus col1, or the row number plus col1 and col4, or just col1, or col1 and col4.  Are the heading rows physically present in the files?  Is the data in the files sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing the specification:

- Are the row numbers physically present in the files? *Yes*
- What combination of columns tells you that the entry in File1 matches the entry in File2? *Row number*
- Are the heading rows physically present in the files? *No (but we change our mind later)*
- Is the data in the files sorted? *Assume no*
- How are records present in File1 but not in File2 handled? *Not specified, but probably requires a third output file.*

The answer will ignore the 'deleted records' problem.

The question observes that this logic finds the records inserted in File2:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next;}!($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

It's close to correct; it should be `!($1 in a)`.  An explicit print is needed to send the output to a file.  For the rest of the logic, we can spot changes in the fields fairly easily:

```
awk 'NR == FNR  { a[$1] = $0; next }
     !($1 in a) { print $0 > "ofile.1"; next }
                { split(a[$1], old);
                  for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
                  {
                      if ($i != old[i])
                      {
                          format = "%-8s  %4d  %d  %s\n"
                          printf format, "File1", $1, i, $i     > "ofile.2";
                          printf format, "File2", $1, i, old[i] > "ofile.2";
                      }
                  }
                }'
```

This produces reasonable output under the given assumptions (heading rows absent).  If in fact the heading rows are present, then you have to capture them and use them (and the file names too):

```
awk 'FNR == 1   { file[++num] = FILENAME; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) head[i] = $i; next }
     NR == FNR  { a[$1] = $0; next }
     !($1 in a) { print $0 > "ofile.1"; next }
                { split(a[$1], old);
                  for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
                  {
                      if ($i != old[i])
                      {
                          format = "%-8s  %4d  %-4s  %s\n"
                          printf format, file[1], $1, head[i], $i     > "ofile.2";
                          printf format, file[2], $1, head[i], old[i] > "ofile.2";
                      }
                  }
                }'
```

And to get the correct headings on the second output file, you need to make some more minor adjustments:

```
awk 'NR == 1    { printf "%-8s  %4s  %-7s  %s\n", "Filename", "Row", "Colname", "Colvalue" > "ofile.2" }
     FNR == 1   { file[++num] = FILENAME; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) head[i] = $i; next }
     NR == FNR  { a[$1] = $0; next }
     !($1 in a) { print $0 > "ofile.1"; next }
                { split(a[$1], old);
                  for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
                  {
                      if ($i != old[i])
                      {
                          format = "%-8s  %4d  %-7s  %s\n"
                          printf format, file[1], $1, head[i], $i     > "ofile.2";
                          printf format, file[2], $1, head[i], old[i] > "ofile.2";
                      }
                  }
                }' File1 File2
```

The sample output from this is:

*ofile.1*

```
3      M     N    O     P
```

*ofile.2*

```
Filename   Row  Colname  Colvalue
File1        1  Col2     Z
File2        1  Col2     B
File1        2  Col3     Y
File2        2  Col3     G
```

If you want blank lines after each record, that's a trivial modification — exercise for the OP.